# Can I have two aggregations between two classes?

Tags: uml

*Note: this question is different from [Can a UML class diagram show two different relationships between two classes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/282006/6605) which is about two relations of different type.*

I have a `Menu` class which contains:

- A bunch of children, which are instances of `MenuItem` class.
- An instance of a `MenuItem` class which corresponds to a very specific menu item (and is not necessarily set for every instance of `Menu` class.)

How am I expected to represent such relation? In other words, is this representation correct:

[image]

or should I remove the second aggregation as being redundant?

Comment: I personally would say "why not?" but my expertise level  doesn't make me feel very confident. By the way, I think that `MenuItem`'s lifecycle is tightly bound to `Menu`'s. Why not use *compositions* instead of "simple" *aggregations*

Comment: @C.Champagne: in the context of the project, menu items are initialized *before* the menu, thus the usage of aggregations. This being said, in the context-less example from my question, compositions make indeed much more sense.

Comment: @MainMa, you may use a composition even if the MenuItem exists earlier than the Menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your description, you are talking about two ways in which a `Menu` instance contains `MenuItem` instances: A set of children and a separate customization item.
This implies that there are two separate, independent, relations between `Menu` and `MenuItem` and that each of them plays an important role in the design.

Your UML diagram should contain all the relations that are needed to convey the ideas of your design. If you omit a relation here, then you are removing important information from your diagram and you will likely end up with software that does not match what you intended to build.

The main difference here with the question you linked to ([Can a UML class diagram show two different relationships between two classes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/282006/6605)) is that there one of the relations (the nesting of the classes) can be regarded as incidental and not representing a core design concept. Such incidental relations can be omitted from a diagram if they would mostly create clutter.